# How do I properly use cancelLocalNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I believe I am using `cancelLocalNotification` improperly.

I have a recurring notification that runs conditionally, which was created using the following code:

```
let localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertAction = "Inactive Membership"
localNotification.alertBody = "Our system has detected that your membership is inactive..."
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
localNotification.repeatInterval = .Minute  

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

This notification successfully runs every single minute (for testing purposes). Obviously, I'd like a way to conditionally remove these notifications, so I've tried to use `cancelLocalNotification` to do so.

**How I think cancelLocalNotification works**

My intuition is that `cancelLocalNotification` will remove all the notifications for that specific notification object. Here's how I'm using it.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

**What actually happens**

I've stepped through my function and verified that the `cancelLocalNotification` code does get called. However, I keep getting my notification every minute.

### My Question

How do I properly cancel a UILocalNotification that has been scheduled?

---

**Full code:**

```
static func evaluateMemberStatusNotifications() {
    let userDefaults = Global.app.userDefaults
    let localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

    print("evaluating profile notifications")
    // is the user active? if so no notification
    let isActive : Bool = userDefaults.valueForKey("ActiveMember") as! Bool // false == inactive

    print("is the user active?")
    if !isActive {
        print("user is not active, checking if notification code has run")

        // if userDefaults is nil for this value, we'll set it to false
        if (userDefaults.valueForKey("ProfileNotificationHasRun") == nil) {
            print("nil! setting ProfileNotificationHasRun to 'false'")
            userDefaults.setValue(false, forKey: "ProfileNotificationHasRun")
        }

        let statusNotification = userDefaults.valueForKey("ProfileNotificationHasRun") as! Bool
        // has this code been run? If not run it
        if !statusNotification {
            print("running notification code")
            // we schedule a notification

            localNotification.alertAction = "Inactive Membership"
            localNotification.alertBody = "Our system has detected that your membership is inactive."
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
            localNotification.category = "status"
            localNotification.repeatInterval = .Day
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "ProfileNotificationHasRun")
        } else {
            print("notification code has already run, time interval has been set")
        }
    } else {
        print("member is active, remove Inactive notification")
        // if the member is active, we remove the notification so the user doesn't
        // keep getting notified
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)

        userDefaults.setValue(false, forKey: "ProfileNotificationHasRun")
    }

}
```

Comment: I've copied the code from your gist into your question since there's not that much of it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `UILocalNotification` (line 3 of your gist) and then cancelling it. That new notification was never scheduled. You need to get the existing, scheduled notification object and cancel that.

You can access your existing, scheduled notifications through the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications` array.

Or you could just cancel all scheduled local notifications by calling `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`.

### UPDATE

Each call to `evaluateMemberStatusNotifications` creates a new instance of `UILocalNotification`, then (depending on the `ActiveMember` value) either configures and schedules that new notification, or tries to delete the new (unscheduled) notification.

Instead, you should just create a new notification in the `!isActive` branch where you want to schedule it.

In the other branch, you need to find the existing notification in the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array and (if you find it) cancel that existing notification.

Since you say you have other notifications that you don't want to mess with, you should use the `userInfo` property of the notification to identify it. For example, when configuring the notification before scheduling it:

```
localNotification.alertAction = "Inactive Membership"
localNotification.alertBody = "Our system has detected that your membership is inactive. You may continue using this application though some features may not be available to you until your membership is reinstated."
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
localNotification.category = "status"
localNotification.repeatInterval = .Day
// *** NEW
localNotification.userInfo = [ "cause": "inactiveMembership"]
```

And when you want to cancel the existing notification:

```
let maybeNotification = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications?.filter({ (notification: UILocalNotification) -> Bool in
    notification.userInfo?["cause"] as? String == "inactiveMembership"
}).first
if let notification = maybeNotification {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: I've amended my answer.

Comment: I can tell this is right already, when you told me that UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications was an array I was able to remove the notification item by calling item[0] inside cancelLocalNotification, so I started looking for a way to identify my notification. Thank you so much for your time rob